# ZF2 soap autodiscover not work with arrayofObjects

Tags: php, web-services, soap, zend-framework2, wsdl

I'm making a soap servet with zf2 and I got a problem with wsdl structure.

my wsdl generated is this :

```
<definitions>
   <types>
      <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://xmlapi.testsoap.com/service">
         <xsd:complexType name="RoomPax">
            <xsd:all>
               <xsd:element name="count" type="xsd:int"/>
               <xsd:element name="adults" type="xsd:int"/>
            </xsd:all>
         </xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfRoomPax">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="item" type="tns:RoomPax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:complexType name="GetHotelAvailRQ">
            <xsd:all>
               <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:int"/>
               <xsd:element name="checkin" type="xsd:string"/>
               <xsd:element name="checkout" type="xsd:string"/>
               <xsd:element name="rooms" type="tns:ArrayOfRoomPax"/>
               <xsd:element name="language" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
            </xsd:all>
         </xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:element name="getHotelAvail">
            <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="getHotelAvailRQ" type="tns:GetHotelAvailRQ"/>
               </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
         </xsd:element>
         <xsd:complexType name="Hotel">
            <xsd:all>
               <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
               <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
            </xsd:all>
         </xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfHotel">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="item" type="tns:Hotel" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:complexType name="HotelAvailRS">
            <xsd:all>
               <xsd:element name="date" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
               <xsd:element name="hotels" type="tns:ArrayOfHotel" nillable="true"/>
            </xsd:all>
         </xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:element name="getHotelAvailResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="getHotelAvailResult" type="tns:HotelAvailRS"/>
               </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
         </xsd:element>
      </xsd:schema>
   </types>
   <portType name="BookingXmlPort">
      <operation name="getHotelAvail">
         <documentation>This method make a search ... ...</documentation>
         <input message="tns:getHotelAvailIn"/>
         <output message="tns:getHotelAvailOut"/>
      </operation>
   </portType>
   <binding name="BookingXmlBinding" type="tns:BookingXmlPort">
      <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <operation name="getHotelAvail">
         <soap:operation soapAction="http://xmlapi.testsoap.com/service#getHotelAvail"/>
         <input>
         <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
         <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
   </operation>
</binding>
<service name="BookingXmlService">
   <port name="BookingXmlPort" binding="tns:BookingXmlBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://xmlapi.testsoap.com/service"/>
   </port>
</service>
<message name="getHotelAvailIn">
   <part name="parameters" element="tns:getHotelAvail"/>
</message>
<message name="getHotelAvailOut">
   <part name="parameters" element="tns:getHotelAvailResponse"/>
</message>
</definitions>
```

It has an arrayofRoomPax when I test in soapUi, it say that can receive zero or more item of type RoomPAx, like this:

```
<getHotelAvailRQ>
   <city>?</city>
   <checkin>?</checkin>
   <checkout>?</checkout>
   <rooms>
      <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
      <item>
         <count>?</count>
         <adults>?</adults>
      </item>
   </rooms>
   <language>?</language>
</getHotelAvailRQ>
```

my problem is When I put 2 items in same level and I test my request object with print_r function I see this structure

```
[city] => ?
 [checkin] => ?
 [checkout] => ?
 [rooms] => stdClass Object
     (
         [item] => Array
             (
                 [0] => stdClass Object
                     (
                         [count] => ?
                         [adults] => ?

                     )

                 [1] => stdClass Object
                     (
                         [count] => ?
                         [adults] => ?
                     )

             )

     )
```

And really I want a structure like this to populate my objects.

```
[city] => ?
 [checkin] => ?
 [checkout] => ?
 [rooms] => array
     (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [count] => ?
                [adults] => ?

            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [count] => ?
                [adults] => ?
            )
     )
```

I'm using Autodiscover class with this config:

```
        $wsdl->setOperationBodyStyle(array('use' => 'literal'));
        $wsdl->setBindingStyle(array('style' => 'document'));

        $wsdl->setComplexTypeStrategy(new \Zend\Soap\Wsdl\ComplexTypeStrategy\ArrayOfTypeSequence);
```

How can I resolve it? 
Thanks.